# Get string names of data frames/objects in list

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list of data frames in R.

```
testList <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

What I'd like to do is apply a function to each data frame in the list, to modify the data frame stored in the environment. Here is pseudocode of what I'm trying to do:

```
>> modify <- function(list.of.dfs){
    for (df in list.of.dfs){
        df$some.new.variable <- some.new.value

>> df
>> (returns new df with new variable created)
```

That's a simple example; for each data frame in the list, the data frame would now have a new variable with some value.

I've almost found a solution. Basically, it iterates through a list and creates a string command for each data frame, then evaluates it. But the only problem is that when it creates a command, it'll pass in the string version of the index variable, not the name of the data frame:

```
modify <- function(data.list, functionName){
  for(i in 1:length(data.list)){
    command <- paste0(varText(data.list),
                      "[[",
                      i,
                      "]] <- ",
                      varText(functionName),
                      "(",
                      varText(data.list),
                      "[[",
                      i,
                      "]])"
                      )
    evaluate <- parse(command)
    print(evaluate)
    eval(evaluate)
  }
  data.list
}
```

where:

```
varText <- function(object){
  deparse(substitute(object))
}
```

So I need to find a way to access data frames, pull their names, and iterate through a list of commands featuring the names of those data frames.

I then want to be able to access those modified data frames in the global environment.

...unless someone knows a better solution to doing this.

**Edit: A reproducible example**

Suppose I create two data frames and add them to the same list:

```
df1 <- data.frame(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
df2 <- data.frame(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
test.list <- list(df1, df2)
```

And I create a function that trivially edits a data frame that's passed in:

```
testFunction <- function(data.frame){
   data.frame$new.variable <- 0
}
```

Then I can use `lapply` as suggested in the answer:

```
lapply(test.list, testFunction)
```

Which returns a list.

However if you call `df1` or `df2`, they remain unchanged. What has been created are modified versions of `df1` and `df2` but they are stored within the list `lapply` creates.

I want to just be able to type

```
df1
df2
```

And have them be modified.

Is there a way to do this so that you don't have to assign the elements of the list `lapply` creates to the names of the variables you want to access?

Much, much appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would call `modify` and what you expect it to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mnel. I've added one – let me know if it isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to apply a function to a list of data frames?

In this instance `lapply()` is your friend and will be far more efficient than a `for()` loop.

Based on your revised example, try something like:

```
# data
df1 <- data.frame(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
df2 <- data.frame(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
test.list <- list(df1, df2)

# function
out.list <- lapply(test.list, function(x) {x$.new.variable <- 0; x})

# name the df's in the list and check the output
names(out.list) <- c("df1", "df2")
str(out.list)
```

This will apply the function to each object within the list, and return the results as a list [with @thelatemail's suggested edit].

If you then want to access the modified dataframes you can just call them by name:

```
out.list$df1
```

Or, if you want to return the df's to the global environment, you can use the following provided you have named the df's using the step above:

```
list2env(out.list ,.GlobalEnv)
```

That should do what you need.

Comment: Not quite, you also have to return the object after changing it, or otherwise only the new value will be returned, e.g.: `lapply(list(data.frame(one=1),data.frame(two=2)), function(x) {x$new <- 1; x} )`

Comment: Hi @AJD, thank you so much for the help. I've added a reproducible example – your answer is almost there. Let me know if I can edit it at all to make it clearer; I'm new to Stack Overflow!